# Debugging Webapps in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tomcat, web-applications

I want to debug a webapp through Eclipse.  The webapp will be running on a Tomcat 7 instance that I have configured within Eclipse, and thus everything, including Tomcat's launch will be done from within Eclipse.

Now, my question is what is the best way to debug the webapp in such a situation.  Is local debugging possible, or the only solution is remote debugging.

I know how to do remote debugging, but given that everything is done from within Eclipse, I wanted to see if there is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click on `Run` -> `Debug Configurations...`. On the left side you should have your tomcat server listed. (if not, you first have to define it in the preferences).

Configure your VM settings and whatever you need, then just click `Debug`in the lower right corner.

Your server should now start in debug mode, and stop on breakpoints.

From now on the server will be included in popdown menu of the Debug-Button in your toolbar.

Alternatively you can add the *Servers* View (`Window` -> `Show View` -> `Servers`), select your server and start it in debug by right-clicking

Comment: Thanks; exactly what I need. I can't believe I had actually missed local debugging.