# How to debug java project compiled with ant in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, tomcat8

I have a java website hosted in a debian VPS server.

When I write new code, I test the web app in my local machine, before to deploy it.

In the VPS server I have ant installed, so I always compile my code in the VPS server and then I put the generated WAR file in the webapp folder of tomcat installed in my local machine to test.

To compile the source code with ant I write the followings commands.

```
ant fetch-deps
ant
```

I need to debug my web app with eclipse. I'd like to have a debug configuration which:

- compiles the web project witn ant, in the same way I do in the VPS
  server
- deploys the generated war to a tomcat server (tomcat server inside
  eclipse should be fine)
- opens a debug session, so that I can put break points in my code and 
  debug my app line by line

I have serached in google, but I can't find a step by step tutorial for my case. I tried to configure my debug with pieces of information I found here and there in the web, but something goes wrong... so I need a step by step explanation.

I tried to activate debug in my local tomcat webserver, but break points were not hitted. It seems that in the debug session with tomcat, eclipse and tomcat are not able to correctly map the WAR file with the source code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228826/debugging-webapps-in-eclipse

Comment: @Kennet this doesn't help me. I already know how to create a debug configuration to debug in tomcat.
I wrote this question because I am missing something in the DETAILS, therefore I need a step-by-step explanation.
The details are the important part.

Answer (score 0):

Using Eclipse Oxygen with the new **Launch group** feature:

- Build and deploy the war with ant. Deploy with ant explained [here](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-deploy-to-tomcat-using-ant.html).
- Create a remote debug configuration.
- Create a **Launch group** configuration (**Run** configurations) and add the build and debug configurations to it.

PS: [add a delay](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45307155/2834978) between launches to allow app to be deployed.